# Is there a way to tell if interface property is not required in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, interface

Is there a way to distinguish if interface property is required, or not in runtime?
Suppose we have:

```
export interface IPagination {
    mode: PaginationMode;
    pageSizes: number[];
    defaultPageSize?: number;
}
```

Now in runtime I need to read a configuration from some JSON file, save it to some property of type IPagination, and want to use interface metadata to check validity of configuration (in my case if I have two configs, one with defaultPageSize and another without, they'd both be valid).
Is this possible to do, using interface information?

Comment: The type system is [erased](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-type-erasure) upon transpilation, so there's no metadata at runtime to use.  For a single interface like `IPagination` you can manually write a [user-defined type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) to perform validation of the parsed JSON.  Do you want help with that?  (Note that we don't know what `PaginationMode` is)

Answer (score 1):

I would use two different types in this case, and a type guard to differentiate them.

```js
export type Pagination = {
  mode: PaginationMode;
  pageSize: number[];
};

export type PaginationWithDefaultPageSize = Pagination & {
  defaultPageSize: number;
};

// Example function that shows how to use a typeguard:
function checkPagination(config: Pagination | PaginationWithDefaultPageSize) {
  hasDefaultPageSize(config)
    ? console.log(`The default page size is ${config.defaultPageSize}`);
    : console.log('This is a normal Pagination config, without a default page size.');
}

// This is the typeguard:
function hasDefaultPageSize(config: Pagination | PaginationWithDefaultPageSize): config is PaginationWithDefaultPageSize {
  return 'defaultPageSize' in config;
}
```

With the typeguard, TypeScript will know that the type of `config` is either `Pagination` or `PaginationWithDefaultPageSize`, and you can access the different properties of those two types.

**Update:**

If you just want to validate that your object is OK and contains all required keys, it is not possible with TypeScript. TypeScript is a transpiler, not a validator.

I would still write a typeguard like this:

```js
function isValidPaginationConfig(config: any | Pagination): config is Pagination {
  return 'mode' in config
    && 'pageSizes' in config
    && Array.isArray(config.pageSizes);
}
```

Comment: This is cool to know if defaultPageSize (which is optional) is missing, but what if configuration has missing say pageSizes? How can I know it isn't valid. And if possible without hardcoding, just using interface metadata?